# Py2neo, add property in relationship

Tags: neo4j, py2neo

I would like to add new property in my relationship. I try something like for node:

`rel = graph.relationship(id)
    p = rel.properties
    p['d'] = 'aaa'
    rel.push()`

But nothing is updated.
I'm using py2neo v3.1.2